# Docker compose yml file compatibility

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently tried to upgrade an existing docker-compose.yml file from version 2.1 to version 3.2.  When `docker-compose up` ran it complained:

```
Unsupported config option for services.webserver: 'mem_limit'
```

Yet [at the upgrading documentation page here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#upgrading) nothing about `mem_limit` is mentioned in the Version 2.x to 3.x section.  I think someone told me secrets handling was changed too, if that was, it isn't mentioned either.  Does anyone know if there is a complete list of changes/compatibility anywhere?

Anyone suggesting going through the Version 3 documentation and discovering the differences myself will, I hope, be down-voted!  :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas) website, under docker compose version 3 you can see that they have replaced some of the variables which also includes *mem_limit* which is not just *memory*:

```
Note: This replaces the older resource constraint options for non swarm mode in Compose files prior to version 3 (cpu_shares, cpu_quota, cpuset, mem_limit, memswap_limit, mem_swappiness), as described in Upgrading version 2.x to 3.x.
```